# где может быть ошибка?

Tags: c

Компилирует код без ошибок, но при открытии .ехе и первого прохода программы, не даёт ввести знак и печатает сразу строку для вывода сообщения о вводе мат.операции и ввода первого числа.

#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

```
while (1) {                                         

    char action;                                    
    long long n1, n2, sum, diff, mult, split;      

    printf("%s", "input +,-,/,* :");               
    scanf("%c", &action);                           

    printf("%s", "input number 1:");                
    scanf("%d", &n1);                               
    printf("%s", "input number 2:");                
    scanf("%d", &n2);                               


    switch (action) {                                     
        case '*':                                       
        mult = n1 * n2;                             
        printf("%s %d\n", "Mult:", mult);           
        break;                                     
    case '+':                                       
        sum = n1 + n2;                              
        printf("%s %d\n", "Sum:", sum);             
        break;                                      
    case '/':                                       
        split = n1 / n2;                            
        printf("%s %d\n", "Split:", split);         
        break;                                      
    case '-':                                                                      
        diff = n1 - n2;                             
        printf("%s %d\n", "Diff:", diff);          
        break;                                      
    }                                               

    n1 = 0;                                          
    n2 = 0;
}                                                   
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Значит, в `scanf("%c", &action);` читается что-то другое. Скорее всего, пробел или перевод строки. Делайте соответствующие проверки. Или читайте знак как строку, а не как символ.

Comment: Вопрос про `scanf()` раз пятидесятый на SO... закройте это как дубликат.